# How to seed a photo in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using paperclip, but not sure how to seed with/without it.

I have a placeholder, in my local path (OSX) as `/Users/me/dev/APP/doc/seeding/300x220.jpg`

My seed file is:

```
p = Photo.new({:description => 'one', :created_at => "Sun, 1 Jan 2012 01:01:01 -0500".to_datetime, :updated_at => "Sun, 1 Jan 2012 01:01:01 -0500".to_datetime })
p.image_file_name = File.open(Rails.root.join('doc', 'seeding', '300x220.jpg'))
p.save!
```

My error is returning:

```
No such file or directory - /Users/me/dev/APP/doc/seeding/300x220.jpg
/Users/me/dev/APP/db/seeds.rb:20:in `initialize'
/Users/me/dev/APP/db/seeds.rb:20:in `open'
/Users/me/dev/APP/db/seeds.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:520:in `load_seed'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:333:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:setup => db:seed => db:seed:common => db:seed:original
```

[Searching the rdoc for paperclip](http://rdoc.info/search/gems/paperclip?q=seed), returns nothing.

Other documents that might be of help:

Schema for Photo:

```
create_table "photos", :force => true do |t|
 t.string   "description"
 t.datetime "created_at",         :null => false
 t.datetime "updated_at",         :null => false
 t.string   "image_file_name"
 t.string   "image_content_type"
 t.integer  "image_file_size"
 t.datetime "image_updated_at"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
photo.image = File.open(file_path)
photo.save!
```

Comment: turned out, you made me check permissions.   They were good, but OSX somehow had it double file extension, causing the issue. (`-rw-r--r--@ 1 me  staff  3605 Jan 20 18:58 300x220.jpg.jpg`)   even though the Finder had it as .jpg   Thanks for helping me verify the syntax..